# Set duration of iAd's Pre-Roll Video Ad

Tags: ios, iad

I have successfully implemented an iAd Pre-Roll Video Ad.

Is there a way to set the duration of the Pre-Roll Video Ad?

In this Apple document, [Monetizing your iOS apps with iAd](https://developer.apple.com/iad/resources/Implementing-iAd-in-Your-iOS-Apps.PDF), it says that we can set the duration to 15, 30, or 60 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document states:

> Pre-Roll Video Ad: The `MPMoviePlayerController` reference and
>   `AVPlayerViewController` reference includes configuration details.
>   Videos that are 15, 30 or 60 seconds in duration are supported.

It does not say that *you* can set the duration of these ads.

The way this reads to me is, Pre-Roll Video Ads will *have* a duration of either 15, 30 or 60 seconds. The test ad delivered by iAd reinforces this interpretation as it is exactly 30 seconds in duration.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the help!